# Wordpress + Memberpress: hide links or content in loop

Tags: wordpress, memberpress

As far as I understand with Memberpress you can hide the content of a page to a user who has no membership for it.

Suppose you have two WP categories (Music and Books) with two corresponding memberships, and user "John" has membership just for Music.

John can still view the reference to Movies, although he cannot enter it.

Is there a way, in a custom template, to hide the link or the taxonomy box for the contents that John has no membership for, so that he doesn't not even know it exists in the website?

Thank you.